# Advantages and/or disadvantages of lazy Racket

Tags: racket

I understand that Racket has strict i.e. eager evaluation, but one can chose lazy evaluation. The limited reading I have done on functional languages suggests that lazy evaluated languages can be more expressive in general, so is there any 'technical' disadvantage in choosing the lazy evaluation option for all Racket programs (in terms of speed, robustness of code, existence of libraries etc...)?

If not, is there a clear philosophical reason for preferring strict evaluation (references accepted)?

Comment: Well strict racket is much older and more mature so it has that going for it. And lazy *pure* languages are actually more expressive than pure strict languages. Thanks to mutation and macros you can have laziness where ever you want with enough headache :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lazy-by-default language is impractical without some sort of accompanying strictness analysis, because lazy evaluation incurs resource overheads that often negates its benefits. You can see this for yourself by playing around in `#lang lazy`, which is a proof-of-concept lazy language that ships with Racket. For all but the smallest toy programs, `#lang lazy` is too slow to be useful.

Ideally, we would have some sort of hybrid lazy-strict language that uses laziness when beneficial but is otherwise strict to avoid wasting resources, but figuring out the optimal balance of lazy or strict is still an open problem. It's not a stretch to say that a significant amount of research produced by the Haskell community over the past few decades has been to combat laziness, trying to find this balance. On the Haskell mailing list or SO topic, you'll frequently find a programmer trying to add strictness to their program that is "too lazy".

Racket has `delay` and `force`, which you can use to leverage laziness when you want, and not pay the overhead when you don't need it. However, there may be some idioms that are easier to reason about in lazy languages, like "tying the knot".

A point in favor of the strict-first approach is that much of the research on hybrid lazy-strict approaches has discovered that most of the time, you only need a small amount of laziness. For example see [this paper on Optimistic Evaluation](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/Papers/optimistic/).

Answer (score 4):

If you are interested in the expressiveness of different languages, then I can recommend "On the Expressive Power of Programming Languages" by Matthias Felleisen. The abstract:

> The literature on programming languages contains an abundance of informal 
>   claims on the relative expressive power of
>   programming languages, but there is no framework for formalizing such
>   statements nor for deriving interesting consequences. As a first step
>   in this direction, we develop a formal notion of expressiveness and
>   investigate its properties. To validate the theory, we analyze some
>   widely held beliefs about the expressive power of several
>   extensions of functional languages. Based on these results, we believe 
>   that our system correctly captures many of the informal ideas
>   on expressiveness, and that it constitutes a foundation for further
>   research in this direction.

http://www.ccs.neu.edu/racket/pubs/scp91-felleisen.ps.gz